# Create two dimensional array from two arrays

Tags: javascript

I've got these two arrays and I need to obtain c. I managed to obtain a solution with two fors and conditionals, but I'm sure something better than O^2 can be obtained with JS.

```
a = [3, 2, 1, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

c = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: I don't think you can do something faster. The only thing you could improve is using a declarative approach rather than an imperative one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fun purpose I wrote it in a coincisive way, hope you like it:

```js
const a = [3, 2, 1, 3];
const b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
const bClone = [...b];

const array = a.map((num, index) =>
  Array.from({ length: num }, () => bClone.shift())
);

console.log(array);
```

Of course controls should be added,
thanks

Comment: This solution mutates `b`, even though `b` is supposed to be a constant.

Comment: Yes I missed that! Thanks for the feedback, so in this case I guess you have to clone b first

Comment: What does coincisive mean (in this or a programming context)?

Comment: HI phhu, with coincisive I meant coincided, like easy to read. Thanks for pointing out this mistype!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that much good background in algorithms but I think this is better than two fors:

```js
let a = [3, 2, 1, 3]
,b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

let head = 0

let result = a.map((e) => {
      let subArr = b.slice(head,head+e)   
      head +=e
      return subArr
  })
  
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: "Suggested edit queue is full", someone else got triggered by indents.

Like your solution

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to combine `map` with `splice`, taking care not to mutate the original array:

```js
const a = [3, 2, 1, 3];
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];

function slices(sizes, arr){
  const clonedArr = [].concat(arr);     // clone array to prevent mutation 
  return sizes.map(size => clonedArr.splice(0,size));
}

console.log(slices(a,b));     // [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Alternatively, avoiding mutation altogether, you could use `slice` with a slightly convoluted `reduce`:

```js
const slicesByReduce = (sizes, arr) => sizes
  .reduce(({start, acc}, size) => ({
    start: start + size,
    acc: [...acc, arr.slice(start, start + size)]
  }),{
    start: 0,
    acc: []
  }).acc;

console.log(slicesByReduce(a,b));     // [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: you don't need to clone an array to use splice. You can use slice instead, which doesn't alter the original array

Comment: True, but here I'm relying splice to make the array shorter each time to save tracking the slice start position.... how would you write this function with `slice`?

Comment: by tracking the slice start position.

Comment: Good thinking... I've added a slightly ugly reducer to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your array of "sizes" and get slices of the second array into the result, like this:

```js
const a = [3, 2, 1, 3]
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

const c = [];
var index = 0;
for (var size of a) {
    c.push(b.slice(index, index + size));
    index += size;
}
  
console.log(c)
//c = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Also, if you are going to work with arrays in JavaScript, please look into:

- initializing variables with var, let and const
- using push()
- for loops

Comment: How is this better than phhu´s solution, which you viewed and commented on before making your solution? If anything, this solution seems more complicated.

Comment: Your comment doesn't add anything to the discussion

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything to the answers that already existed before you posted it.